# Illegal break statement in fetch

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fetch-api

I have a for-loop and within the loop I'm doing a fetch. I wish to stop the loop once the API returns a favorable response. But my `break` doesn't work.

```
async function printy(message) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        await waitforme(2000);
        console.log(i);
        
        fetch('https://mn.test/api/v1/is-verified?' + new URLSearchParams({
            message: message}))
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            console.log("Status: " + response.is_verified);
            
            if (response.is_verified == 'yes' ) {
                break;
                alert("Verified");
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });           
        
    }
    console.log("Loop execution finished!)");
}
```

Comment: Your `break` is inside a `.then()` callback function.

Comment: Also don't mix `.then()` callbacks with `async/await`.

Comment: Also don't run asynchronous stuff in `for` loops...

Comment: Consider using [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any)?

Comment: @Cerbrus if I don't run async stuff in for loop, how can I continuously check for changes in server?

Comment: @Cerbrus why not? It's the easiest way to execute async tasks sequentially

Comment: Because there's usually a better way to handle a list of async calls...

Answer (score 1):

Because it's in a different function run at a different place (outside of the scope of your loop.)

However anything that returns a promise (has a .then()) you can just await it. So this:

```js
async function printy(message) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        console.log(i);
        
        const result = await fetch('https://mn.test/api/v1/is-verified?' + new URLSearchParams({message: message}));
        const response = await result.json();
        console.log("Status: " + response.is_verified);
        
        if (response.is_verified == 'yes' ) {
            alert("Verified");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

would be what your're looking for.

Comment: When I followed your code, I'm getting the error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'response' before initialization`

Comment: Well yeah because response hasn't been initialized yet and it should be result.json